# How to compile to named files by default?

Tags: jekyll

I am starting with Jekyll and [the docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/) mention the possibility to generate

- either named HTML files (`http://example.com/about.html`)
- or directories and index.html ones (`http://example.com/about/index.html`).

A fresh installation of Jekyll with the default settings compiles an `about.md` file to `http://example.com/about/index.html`.

**How to change the default behaviour to generate named HTML files?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [permalinks](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/). The default value for pages is `/:path/:basename`, which leads to directories and index.html as you noticed. In the YAML Front Matter of `about.md`, you can add:

```
permalink: /:path/about.html
```

Alternatively, you can modify your configuration in `_config.yml` to change the behaviour for all pages:

```
permalink: /:path/:basename.html
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the global solution but get a `jekyll 3.2.1 | Error: undefined method 'basename' for #<Jekyll::Drops::UrlDrop:0x00000002e713f8>` when restarting jekyll. When trying the specific solution for `about.md` I realized that there was, by default, a permalink entry there. I removed it and I got the "named HTML" behaviour (by default). Adding `permalink: /:path/about.html` also worked.